# My configurable products need to have view details button instead of Addto Cart button

Tags: magento-2.1, product-view, view

How can I replace the add to cart button with a view details button for my configurable products? I searched everywhere but could only find solutions for Magento 1.9 not 2.1.8.

Comment: can you tell where you want this button?

Comment: When User views products in a category and all the products are listed with the add to cart button. I want the view details button there instead.

Comment: you need to customize your category list page file for this.

Comment: I know how to do that I think but how do I create a custom button?